# Regex how to find start of the line and end of line

Tags: php, regex

What would be the regex to find the start and end of texts and write a php function.

Example texts:

```
Juice Extractor
1L Juice Jug
Easy Operating
2 Speed Settings
Stainless Steel Blade
Safety Lock
Detachable Parts
Dishwasher Safe
```

I would like to find start and end to add `<li></li>` to each line using php function/regex.

So return result should look like:

```
<li>Juice Extractor</li>
<li>1L Juice Jug</li>
<li>Easy Operating</li>
<li>2 Speed Settings</li>
<li>Stainless Steel Blade</li>
<li>Safety Lock</li>
<li>Detachable Parts</li>
<li>Dishwasher Safe</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$text = "Juice Extractor
1L Juice Jug
Easy Operating
2 Speed Settings
Stainless Steel Blade
Safety Lock
Detachable Parts
Dishwasher Safe";

$rows = explode("\n", $text);
$html = implode("</li>\n<li>", $rows);
$html = "<li>" . $html . "</li>";

echo $html;
```

PS: If you want to use browser new lines, you should replace `\n` with `<br>` in `implode`. If the input text is with `<br>` instead of `\n`, you should replace that too in `explode`